# c# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement

I'm trying to work out if something does not exist in the table.  I'm telling it to see if the `UserInfo` contains information for `user`.

```
UserInfo Character = db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user);
if (Character.Username == null || Character.Username.Length == 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But I get an error on the `if` statement.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: if (Character == null )  { /* do stuff */ }   // FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a test on Character to know if it's null. If that's the case, you'll have the exception you mentionned.

So just do this :

```
if(Character != null)
{
    //Your code can now safely call the Properties/Methods/etcetc...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the `db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user)` expression returned `null` because it didn't find any matching records that satisfy the filter criteria.

so:

```
UserInfo Character = db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user);
if (Character == null || Character.Username == null || Character.Username.Length == 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: i know the db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user) returned null and i want to do something because it has

Comment: @SamWoodcock, OK, then use an `if` expression to test its value: `if (Character == null) { ... }` before attempting to access its properties `Character.Username`.

Comment: you still get the error if db or UserInfoes is null, that should be your problem

Comment: @hcb, no, because the OP said that he is getting the exception on the if statement which clearly indicates that the LINQ query in the first line executed successfully, it just returned null.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in the comments that you know that `db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user)` returned null. Hence, `Character` is `null` and you need to check this case separately:

```
if (Character == null ||                 // this line is new
    Character.Username == null || 
    Character.Username.Length == 0) 
{ 
    //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the error occurs on the `if` statement, `Character` is `null`.  You need to add a check for `if (Character == null)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error on the if statement, then it is likely that your search:-

```
UserInfo Character = db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == user);
```

Has not found any record matching where **Username** equals **user**.  When that happens, the value of Character is `null`.

Your issue is that you are trying to call a property on something that doesn't exist.  You need to perform a check to ensure that `Character` is not `null` before calling any of its members.

```
if ( Character != null ) 
{
   // Can now safely call properties on the Character object
}
else
{
   // Take the appropriate action for circumstances where we can't
   // find a user by username
}
```

Comment: but i need to do stuff if character is null

Answer (score 1):

First you should check whether Character is null, then later you should check for remaining in Character.

```
if(Character != null)
{
   if(Character.Username == null || Character.Username.Lenght == 0)
   {
       //Do Stuff
   }
}
```

EDIT:

or simply you can check only the Character, like

```
if(Character == null)
{
//Do Stuff
}
```